# How does this piece of code work?

Tags: c++, c

1.)

```
int i;

for(i=1;i<5,i<8;i++){

}
printf("%d",i);
```

2.)

```
int i;

for(i=1;i<18,i<6;i++){

}
printf("%d",i);
```

output for 1.) is 8 while for 2.) is 6

I am not getting how the code works, Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What part is troubling you? The `for` loop? The comma operator? `printf`? Be specific.

Answer (score 5):

The `,` operator evaluates to its last operand.

`i < 18, i < 6` becomes false when `i` is `6`.

Answer (score 5):

### Comma operator ( , )

> The comma operator (,) is used to separate two or more expressions that are included where only one expression is expected. **When the set of expressions has to be evaluated for a value, only the rightmost expression is considered**.

Hence:

```
for(i=1;i<5,i<8;i++)
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(i=1;i<8;i++)
```

Which evaluates value of `i` to `8`

And

```
for(i=1;i<18,i<6;i++)
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(i=1;i<6;i++)
```

Which evaluates value of `i` to `6`

---

Standerdese Reference:

**C++11 Standard §5.18:**

> The comma operator groups left-to-right.
>
> expression:
>   assignment-expression
>   expression , assignment-expression
>
> **A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded- value expression (Clause 5)83**. Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. **The type and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category as its right operand,** and is a bit-field if its right operand is a glvalue and a bit-field.

Comment: You should also mention how to fix it &&

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think there is anything to fix.I am pretty much sure OP is not trying to impose two conditions for the `for` loop here. For the simple reason that `i<5` and `i<8` and won't make any sense.I believe the OP's Q was actually the curiosity about two conditions in the for loop and that which one takes effect.

Comment: I missed that they were both i.